# Kotlin function reified parameter with parametrized return type

Tags: generics, kotlin, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

I use an in-house Java framework containing the following classes (simplified for demonstration):

```java
    public interface SomeAction<T, R> {
        R run(T t);
    }

    public class ConcreteAction implements SomeAction<Integer, String> {

        @Override
        public String run(Integer arg) {
            return "abc";
        }
    }

    public class ActionFactory {

        public <A extends SomeAction<T, R>, T, R> SomeAction<T, R> create(Class<A> clz) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
            return clz.newInstance();
        }
    }
```

Calling the factory method from Kotlin in a java-way works ok:

```
ActionFactory().create(ConcreteAction::class.java).run(1)
```

Then I created the following extension method to make it more concise:

```
    inline fun <reified A : SomeAction<T, R>, T, R> ActionFactory.create(): SomeAction<T, R> {
        return create(A::class.java)
    }
```

But a call to `ActionFactory().create<ConcreteAction>().run(1)` fails with the error `3 type arguments for inline fun ...`

Are there any ways to make it work without touching the java code?

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin does not allow calling a generic function while specifying only a part of the type parameters.  If you want to call `create` with explicit type parameters, you have to specify all three of them:

```
ActionFactory().create<ConcreteAction, Int, String>().run(1)
```

Comment: That's what I wanted to avoid. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this may not work with actual code depending on what exactly you simplified out. But given this setup, it may be reasonable to assume that the return value of `create` will actually be an instance of `A`, in which case

```
inline fun <reified A : SomeAction<*, *>> ActionFactory.create(): A {
    return create(A::class.java) as A
}

ActionFactory().create<ConcreteAction>().run(1)
```

will work. The assumption should be documented and tests added if you go that way!